Compute a truncated binomial expectation accurately
I need to compute the following expectation over a binomial random variable
$$E_{S \sim \rm{Binom}(\frac{k}{M}; N)} \left[\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^S 1_{\{S \leq k\}}\right] = \sum_{s=0}^k \binom{N}{s} \left(\frac{k}{M}\right)^s \left(1 - \frac{k}{M}\right)^{N-s} \left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^s.$$
Typical ranges of the variables are $0 < k \leq 256$, $M = N = 10^9$. If $k = N$, this can be evaluated nicely using the decomposition of a Binomial RV in terms of independent Bernoulli's. If the term $\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^s$ is not there, this is the cumulative distribution function of a Binomial, which equals an incomplete Beta integral, and is numerically quite stable. But how do I deal with the above hybrid formula, in a numerically stable manner? I don't need it to be fast, just giving me sensible numbers instead of nan or something $> 1$.
Update: for completeness, the sum can be rewritten by a hypergeometric function
$$\sum_{s=0}^k \binom{N}{s} p^s q^{N-s} = q^N\left((1 + p/q)^N - (p/q)^{k+1} \binom{N}{k+1} {}_2F_1(1, k-N + 1; k + 2; -p/q)\right),$$
where
\begin{align*}
{}_2F_1(a, b; c; z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n} \frac{z^n}{n!}.
\end{align*}
But for $N$ very large, this runs into numeric overflow. The sum terminates after $n > N - k + 1$, but it's not worth trading off a sum of $k+1$ terms with one with many more terms.

Look for logspace addition (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233445/how-to-calculate-sums-in-log-space-without-underflow) in whatever language you're computing with. Then you can calculate each of the product terms on the log scale (e.g. in R, each term would be lchoose(N,s) + s*(log(k)-log(M)) + (N-s)*log(1-k/M) + s*(log(k-1) - log(k)))

Even without any algorithmic tricks, this is non-problematic for double-precision floats.  An extreme example in R is M <- N <- 1e9; k <- 256; s <- seq(0, k); sum(exp(lchoose(N, s) + s * (log(k - 1) - log(M)) + (N - s) * (log(M-k) - log(M))))

@whuber (Ben Bolker) Thanks. Is there an equivalent of lchoose in python (scipy, etc)? The large binomial coefficient seems to be what gave me the nan/inf.

There are equivalents in just about any computing platform, because binomial coefficients are originally computed in terms of log gamma functions.  Even Excel supports this (and has for a long time)!  See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.loggamma.html.

BTW, within your range of variables you can do the sum the old-fashioned way with a simple loop requiring nothing but basic arithmetic.  This works because none of the terms will underflow (the initial one is the smallest, giving a quick simple test): x <- a <- (1 - k / M)^N; for (i in s[-1]) {   x <- x + (a <- a * (N - i) / i * (k / M) / (1 - k / M) * (k - 1) / k) }; (x)

@whuber thanks. with your help problem solved indeed. I just coded my own lchoose with
def lchoose(N, s):
    return sum(math.log(N - i) - math.log(s - i) for i in range(s))

The hypergeometric ${}_2F_1$ formulation gets overflow, so it's better to just compute the sum directly.

FWIW for most ranges it would be faster to construct lchoose by using log-gammas ...

This expression appears to cancel down to a simpler form:
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Your Expectation} 
&\equiv& \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^S \cdot \mathbb{I}(S \leqslant k) \bigg| S \sim \text{Bin}(N,\tfrac{k}{M}) \bigg] \\[10pt]
&=& \sum_{s=0}^k \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^s \text{Bin}(s|N,\tfrac{k}{M}) \\[6pt]
&=& \sum_{s=0}^k \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^s {{N}\choose{s}}  \left(\frac{k}{M}\right)^s \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^{N-s} \\[6pt]
&=& \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^N \sum_{s=0}^k {{N}\choose{s}} \frac{\left(\frac{k}{M}\right)^s}{\left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^s} \cdot \left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^s \\[6pt]
 &=& \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^N \sum_{s=0}^k {{N}\choose{s}}\frac{\left(\frac{k-1}{M}\right)^s}{\left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^s} \\[6pt]
&=& \left(1-\frac{k}{M}\right)^N \sum_{s=0}^k {{N}\choose{s}}\left(\frac{k-1}{M-k}\right)^s  \\[6pt]
&=& \left[\frac{1-\frac{k}{M}}{1-\frac{k-1}{M-k}}\right]^N \sum_{s=0}^k {{N}\choose{s}}\left[\frac{k-1}{M-1}\right]^s \left[1-\frac{k-1}{M-1}\right]^{N-s} \\[6pt]
&=& \left[\frac{1-\frac{k}{M}}{1-\frac{k-1}{M-k}}\right]^N \sum_{s=0}^k \text{Bin} \bigg( s \bigg| N, \frac{k-1}{M-k} \bigg) \\[6pt]
&=& \left[\frac{1-\frac{k}{M}}{1-\frac{k-1}{M-k}}\right]^N \mathbb{P}\bigg( S \leqslant k \bigg| S \sim \text{Bin}(N, \tfrac{k-1}{M-k}) \bigg), \\[6pt]
\end{eqnarray}
which is a simple product involving the binomial CDF with adjusted probability parameter $p=\tfrac{k-1}{M-1}$.  You'd still want to work with logs for the calculation (presumably) and maybe you'd choose to simplify the term out the front, but this expression should be easier than what you started with.

This algebraic reduction is correct but unnecessary, as the code in my comments to the question shows.

Yes, it was clear that the calculation could be done accurately and OP's underlying problem was certainly solved. However, there are various reasons why a direct algebraic solution might turn out to be valuable as an answer here. Not least, seeing how such cancellations and manipulations can be done can be instructive but there's also potentially future cases where the improvement in speed might be helpful.

@Glen_b: Great answer (+1).  I've taken the liberty of cleaning it up a bit and making your answer a bit more definite.  Please feel free to revert if you prefer your initial version.

No, your version is much better, thank you

Thanks. But shouldn't the first line be $\mathbb{E} \bigg[ \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^S \cdot \mathbb{I}(S \leqslant k) \bigg| S \sim \text{Bin}(N,\tfrac{k}{M}) \bigg]$ instead? Also assuming correctness of the 3rd line, I am not following your 4th line: where did the factor $(\frac{k-1}{k})^s$ come from? I would be a little surprised if Wolfram didn't come up with a formula that involves something simpler than ${}_2F_1$, e.g., the incomplete Beta integral, which is your conclusion. And apology for reversing the arguments in the binomial notation.

If we take your expression of $(1 - k/M)^S$ instead of $(1 -1/k)^S$, then of course it's just $(1 + k/M)^N (1-k/M)^N = (1-k^2/M^2)^N$, simply by the binomial formula for $(1 + k/M)^N$.
